# Spatial overlay data from many lines into a single line

Tags: postgis

Hello I have joined lines in my data set into longer lines (based on similar attributes) to reduce the number of rows in my data set. Now I want to take the information from the original smaller lines and update it into the larger lines (two different tables). I would like to concatenate the attributes coming from many lines into the columns for the larger single line. I'm using postGIS for this. thanks